# How to get RadioGroup value from different Activity

Tags: java, android

I am creating a Fitness Application with Android Studio. In this application, I have multiple Activities (6). In my SixthActivity, I want to be able to grab the selected radio button from the radio group in the ThirdActivity. However, when I do this, the value is empty (""), rather than the choice the user chose in the ThirdActivity.

I have tried using the experience Radio Button but it does not work either.

```
//Third Activity.java 

thirdRadioGroup = findViewById(R.id.thirdRadioGroup);

    int radioIdExperience = thirdRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    //experience = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioIdExperience);


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SixthActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Experience", radioIdExperience);
    //startActivity(intent);



//SixthActivity.java


    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String experience =intent.getStringExtra("Experience");



         sixthTextView.setText(experience);
```

I would like the textview in the SixthActivity to populate based on the choice the user made in the ThirdActivity radioGroup. For example, the three choices in the RadioGroup are :

0 -6 months
6 - 12 months
1 + year

Depending on whichever choice the user chooses in ThirdActivity I want it to display in the textview in the SixthActivity.

Comment: It isn't obvious where each part is executed. You should call `getCheckedRadioButtonId` just before you want to create and start the intent of the sixth activity and put the value in it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem :

According to your code . YOu are sending an Integer value to SixthActivity and Saving in String variable

ThirdActiivity

**int** radioIdExperience = thirdRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

SixthActivity

**String** experience =intent.getStringExtra("Experience");

Solutions :
Make sure you are sending correct value and check this on THirdActivity first before sending .
Then Check the sent value on SixthActivity

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static public class an integer array as data member, and keep on populating the array after every subsequent startActivity(). And finally access that array in your sixth activity

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
String experience = intent.getStringExtra("Experience");
```

to:

```
String experience = String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra("Experience"));
```